# Stuff working in firefox goes wrong in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, request

I got some stuff going quite wrong in chrome, while in firefox there is no problem:
When clicking a kind of button i made, no requests are sent.
When trying to give a source to the iframe using the web console, nothing happens, no requests are sent, no error is given.
My code is:

```
 <ul id="navigation" style="height: 500px; border-right-width: 1px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
    <li><a class="link1" id="save_li">Save</a></li>
    <li><a class="link2" id="recover_li">Recover</a></li>

</ul>
<div id="frame_div" style="height: 500px; width: 574px; padding-left: 146px;">
  <iframe id="frame_opened" style="width: 100%;" height="100% overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;" scrolling="no">
</div>
```

The js(called on window load):

```
   function addListeners()
   {
     document.getElementById('save_li').addEventListener('click', function () {
            frame_opened.src="save.php";
            }, false);
      document.getElementById('recover_li').addEventListener('click', function () {
            frame_opened.src="recover.php";
            }, false);
   }
```

css:

```
  #navigation {
  float: left;
  border-right:1px solid #999;
  padding:10px 0px;
  width:20%;
  padding-left: 1px;
}
#navigation a  {
  display:block;
  background:url(navigation.png);
  height:47px;
  text-indent:-9000px;
}
```

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: I've done this before, but the only thing I can remember that I did differently is that I didn't use `frame_opened` I targeted the frame by id (i.e., I used something more like `document.getElementById("#frameId").src = "recover.php"`). It is *possible* that chrome doesn't like `frame_opened`.

Comment: Not to call anyone out, whoever they are, but I don't understand why your question was downvoted...

Comment: I can't understand the downvote neither the close question vote, but everyone is free to have and express an opinion.
I will try it with '#'but as far as I know it's not needed, it always worked in both chrome and firefox. I tried it a couple of days ago when inviting my friends to an event and worked in chrome without the '#'.

It still remains a weird behaviour.
Thanks

Comment: So what changed since then?

Comment: I am not on my computer now, I will try your suggestion in about half and hour when I can reach it and tell you if anything changes. It's on a localhost there so I can't try it yet elsewhere

Comment: @VoidKing Doesn't work with '#' either

Comment: Okay, if you'll give me a bit, I will try to look over everything and see if I can offer any other suggestions. I know, browser cross-compatibility is such a drag, lol.

Comment: I didn't realize that "frame_opened" *was* the id of the frame. My apologies for that. I would have expected this: `document.getElementById('save_li').addEventListener('click', function () {
            frame_opened.src="save.php";` to be: this: `document.getElementById('save_li').addEventListener('click', function () {
            document.getElementById("frame_opened").src="save.php";` but you say that its working in non-chrome browsers so, idk. Perhaps try that? Also are you familiar with jQuery? The jQuery equivalent of this code may not have problems in Chrome

Comment: I also tried it like that already :)
I need to get familiar with both AJAX and JQuery as soon as possible, since I keep running into problems that may be solved with them, but I don't know much about any of them yet

Comment: Dude, you are in for a treat with the both of those. The trickier of the two to nail is, of course, AJAX, but once you get it, it is irreplaceable! Server side manipulation from the client-side is priceless! I freaking love AJAX. As for jQuery, that is MUCH easier to employ, so I would definitely learn that first, plus your knowledge of CSS selectors will come in very handy with jQuery (also jQuery has many handy AJAX functions itself, like `$.getJSON` or my personal favorite `$.ajax` where you get to set whether or not it is asynchronous). Still looking at your code and will get back soon

Comment: For an example: **JavaScript**:  `document.getElementById("frame_opened")` = **jQuery**:  `$("#frame_opened")` So you can see how much time this can save you. And that's just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better (yes I'm still looking, lol, sry I'll quit typing after this xD), I have done some CRAZY CRAZY script manipulation with iframes before (much of which was changing the `src`), so I know it is totally possible to do what you want in and out of Chrome

Comment: Well, thanks :)
I'm new to web development- i could as well say I am quite new to development in general, however I've been doing some Java and C++ and a very little bit of Scala. I am doing this project for some school contest, but also to learn as much as possible :D
Next steps are JQuery and AJAX

Comment: What do you use for server-side code (I'll probably be frowned on for saying this but I prefer WebMatrix-webpages w/C#)?  If you don't have a server-side language environment yet, you'll need that before you can unleash the power of AJAX.

Comment: I am using PHP as server-side language.

Comment: Oh yeah, duh, I knew that from your code. lol, sry

Comment: Why do your links contain no `href` attributes? Consider styling a `<span>` element like a link with CSS instead?

Comment: I don't want a `href`, because I want things to go to the iframe. And the `ul` looks like a nice panel with buttons :D

Comment: Are those the buttons you can't get to work?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. The source of `frame_opened` doesn't change

Comment: I will be right back, one of our employees has come across the threat of a virus, and I can't seem to see him in the list of machines I can remote into. I'll let you know as soon as I'm back. Till then, if you add the `cursor: pointer;` style to your `#navigation a` rule you'll get the standard pointer for you buttons

Comment: The cursor looks like it should already :)

Comment: Oh right, they're `<a>` elements. I confused myself because I never style `<a>` elements to look like buttons, I style buttons to act like `<a>` elements instead.

Comment: It might not be a good behavior to do it like I do (?), however it does look nicely and it does its job (at least in firefox :D)

Comment: I can't see much of anything when I copy your code the jsFiddle, so it's kind of hard to diagnose this one. We may just have to play a guessing game here. One thing that might be the cause is this: In jQuery the event for click is `click` traditionally in javascript I thought it was `onclick` try changing that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28469/discussion-between-voidking-and-bujanca-mihai)